# The electric and magnetic field, reaching to infinity

Tags: magnetic-fields, photons, electrons, electric-fields, quantum-electrodynamics

I have difficulty’s to accept that the electric and magnetic field components of photons as well as of electrons and the other subatomic particles are extended to infinity. For practical use that does not play any role. We observe, that a photon in some distance to the boundaries of a broad enough slit goes through undisturbed while in a narrow slit the photon gets deflected. (Of course from the theoretical point of view with it’s infinite extend of fields, a little deflection happens.)

The claimed extend to infinity has some weaknesses.
How the fields of a photon (electron) are going through the wall around a slit? Even if they go through as phononic excitations, this takes time and some dissipation takes place. The photon (electron) is not the same behind the slit.
Furthermore a quantization of electric and magnetic fields is unthinkable finite extend of these fields. Otherwise the (hypothetical) quanta of these fields would be infinite small.

Is the assumption of infinity of electric and magnetic fields a historical artifact to which no attention is paid or is it a theoretical necessity?

Answer (score 0):

> I have difficulty’s to accept that the electric and magnetic field components of photon

The photon does not have any electric or magnetic field per se, in contrast to charged massive particles. The photon has a wavefunction, which in various solutions of a quantized maxwell equation carry information about the A potential or the electric and magnetic fields that will be built up by confluece of zillions of such photons, bu the real particle has no electric or magnetic field. By "real I mean  the photon defined in the [elementary particle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_particle) table of the standard model.

Who is claiming that the *photon* has an electric/magnetic field? let alone going to infinity? You should  give  a link. In the emergent classical field the electric and magnetic fields have a fixed average value and no infinite extent.

> How the fields of a photon (electron) are going through the wall around a slit? Even if they go through as phononic excitations, this takes time and some dissipation takes place. The photon (electron) is not the same behind the slit

So single photons have no electric or magnetic fields.

As for electrons , it is their probability of interacting with the fringe fields of the slits that "goes around", i.e. has different values that build an  interference pattern. **Not the electrons themselves who leave a [point footprint one at a tim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment#Interference_of_individual_particles)e**.

> Is the assumption of infinity of electric and magnetic fields a historical artifact

If you call classical electromagnetism historical artifact, yes , static fields extend to infinity. In quantum electrodynamics the [exchange of virtual photons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_forces_and_virtual-particle_exchange) is used at the limit going to infinity to be consistent with the classical picture of static electricity and magnetism.